# What is the correct way to check for null values in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
IF purpose = null THEN
   v_purpose := '';
ELSE
   v_purpose := ' for ' || purpose;
END IF;
```

When purpose is null, it still goes to the else...why?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct test is

```
IF purpose IS NULL THEN
```

This is because `NULL` is not a *value* stored in a field.  It is an *attribute*  about the field stored elsewhere (but within in the row).

Setting a field to `NULL` appears to be an ordinary assignment so it is seems perfectly orthogonal to expect testing for it by direct comparison.  However, for it to work as it does, I surmise the SQL assignment primitive has a magic hidden aspect which diverts assignment of the special symbol `NULL` into setting an attribute and not the field.

Comment: While your solution is correct, but your explanation is irrelevant and unhelpful because you have described the implementation, not the behaviour of the SQL language regarding nulls (queries shouldn't care *how* it happens, only *what* happens)

Comment: @Bohemian:  I disagree.  It is extremely helpful to understand something about the implementation as insight into the philosophy of the construct.  If that had been done when the OP was introduced to `NULL`, this question would never have arisen.

Comment: I have to agree with @Bohemian here. The implementation details are irrelevant since null may or may not be stored in the field. The issue here is three-value logic whereby the result of a boolean expression can be `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`. In this case comparing anything to a `NULL` with an equality condition will return `NULL`

Comment: @Bohemian:  I have slightly reworded the apparently controversial explanatory statement.  Also, I added a more philosophical paragraph.  How does it sit with you?

Comment: @MikeMeyers: ditto.  (Two response at-signs in one comment are not allowed.)

Answer (score 5):

NULL is a special value in SQL that cannot be compared using the equality operator. You need to use special operators `IS` and `IS NOT` when testing if a value is NULL.

Here's a [good overview of the idea](http://psoug.org/reference/null.html). And an excerpt:

> NOTE: Null In Oracle is an absence of information. A null can be
>   assigned but it cannot be equated with anything, including itself.
>   NULL values represent missing or unknown data. NULL values are not an
>   integer, a character, or any other specific data type. Note that NULL
>   is not the same as an empty data string or the numerical value '0'.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the expression `purpose = null` is unknown, regardless of what `purpose` is (see @Paul Sasik's answer for more details).  Since it's unknown, it's not necessarily true, so execution bypasses the inside of the `IF` block and falls into the `ELSE` block.